# VB.NET - How to convert user input into money format

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox in which the user can only type in integers. I want to be able to send this to a database as an integer, but display it in a currency format. For example, 123456 becomes $123,456.

Comment: Take a look at this article [Format currency vb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In a WinForm Application you can use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) which could display data in one format (e.g. currency) but actual value will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

```
    Dim number As Integer

    number = 123456

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C2}", number))
```